# Multiple dropdown using "aweCheckbox" working good, but when want to set "other" option related jquery not working for checkbox check uncheck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

**Multiple dropdown using "aweCheckbox" working good, but when want to set "other" option related jquery not working for checkbox check uncheck**

**My Code Snippet:**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

...
...

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Grade</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="grades" id="grades" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
                <?php foreach($allGradeList as $grd){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $grd;?>"><?php echo $grd;?></option>
                <?php } ?>   
            </select>
            <div id="gradeErr" class="err"></div>
        </div>  
</div>

...
...

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').multiselect({
        templates: { // Use the Awesome Bootstrap Checkbox structure
        li: '<li class="checkList"><a tabindex="0"><div class="aweCheckbox aweCheckbox-danger"><label for=""></label></div></a></li>'
        },
        numberDisplayed:1,
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Grade'
    });
    $('.multiselect-container div.aweCheckbox').each(function(index) {

        var id = 'grade-' + index,
        $input = $(this).find('input'); 

        // Associate the label and the input
        $(this).find('label').attr('for', id); 
        $input.attr('id', id);

        // Remove the input from the label wrapper
        $input.detach();

        // Place the input back in before the label
        $input.prependTo($(this));

        $(this).click(function(e) {
            // Prevents the click from bubbling up and hiding the dropdown
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

When page loads.. it looks like in browser inspect (plz find screenshot)
[image]

**Want To Implement: When we will select "other" option then previously selected option should be unchecked. And when we select any option rather than other then "other" option should be unchecked.**

**Trying With Code Snippet:**

```
 $('#grades').on("change",function() { 
    var selGrade = $(this).val(); 
    
    if(selGrade.indexOf("Other") != -1){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').closest('li').removeClass('active');
        $('input[value="Other"]').prop('checked',true);
        $('input[value="Other"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('input[value="'+selGrade+'"]').prop('checked',true);
        $('input[value="'+selGrade+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
        $('input[value="Other"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
        $('input[value="Other"]').closest('li').removeClass('active');
    }
 })
```

But not working properly (getting unchecked values also).. please suggest me changes